# 504 Error; Request could not be satisfied; S3 Static Website

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

- I am attempting to check my website using my s3 bucket link, which works fine. But my Cloudfront link does not work. I get a 504 request could not be satisfied.

Resources:
MyWebsite:
Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
Properties:
AccessControl: PublicRead
WebsiteConfiguration:
IndexDocument: index.html
BucketName: mcderkaderkas-first-website

BucketPolicy:
Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
Properties:
PolicyDocument:
Id: MyPolicy
Version: 2012-10-17
Statement:
- Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
Effect: Allow
Principal: "*"
Action: "s3:GetObject"
Resource: !Join
- ""
- - "arn:aws:s3:::"
- !Ref MyWebsite
- /*
Bucket: !Ref MyWebsite

MyDistribution:
Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
Properties:
DistributionConfig:
DefaultCacheBehavior:
ViewerProtocolPolicy: allow-all
TargetOriginId: mcderkaderkas-first-website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
DefaultTTL: 0
MinTTL: 0
MaxTTL: 0
ForwardedValues:
QueryString: false
PathPattern: /*
Origins:
- DomainName: mcderkaderkas-first-website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Id: mcderkaderkas-first-website.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
CustomOriginConfig:
OriginProtocolPolicy: match-viewer
Enabled: "true"
DefaultRootObject: index.html